# What's the url queryvar for a taxnomy archive?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives

I know I can query for a term archive like this:

```
index.php?taxonomy_name=term_name
```

But how to have a page with all the terms? So a 'taxonomy home'? How to query it? I mean something like this:

```
index.php?taxonomy=taxonomy_name
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work. There must be some other way. Maybe.

Comment: There is no such thing as an archive of terms, archives contain posts, the loop only outputs posts.

Comment: @Milo as an answer please :)

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png as you can see there are 2 generic templates (taxonomy-taxonomy and taxonomy). I guess they whould serve for a taxonomy archive, not single term archive. So the question is: how to reach them with plain GET queryvars (not pretty urls)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below code-

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => $_GET['taxonomy'], // It will get the taxonomy name from HTTP get variable.
    'hide_empty' => false, // If you need to hide the empty taxonomy or not.
) );
```

Now the `$terms` will be an array if there is any taxonomy or taxonomies other wise it will through a `WP_Error` instance. Run a `foreach` loop and decorate it as your wish. For more information [read this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).

Comment: No, I need the url query vars, if any. I've got no problem in doing on-page manual queries, I can do quite about anything. My problem is that I'm building a custom routes/urls system and I need something that points to an archive template featuring all the terms of a specific taxonomy. But I think that probably it's not a current wp feature.

Comment: @Stratboy There isn't an archive template by default. You'll need to create a custom page template for this. I've done it before; if you have a hierarchical taxonomy, you can create one custom page template for the top level term, then after that you can customize the taxonomy archive template for sub-pages, and just get the child terms for that term.

Comment: Please see my comment on the main question. Apparently here are 2 templates that serve the purspose: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png